# Finding an area using $r = 13\cos \theta$, $r = 6 + \cos \theta$

Tags: polar-coordinates

I have these:

> $$r = 13\cos \theta\quad  r = 6 + \cos \theta$$

I am trying to find the area. Would anyone please help?

Comment: You need to find the intersections. Set them equal to find for the angles $\pi/3$ and $\5pi/3$  These angles are needed to establish boundary values for your graphThen make a graph and use the area formula for polars, which should be in your book or notes: integral 0.5r² d$\theta$ Subtract the smaller area (from the inner curve) from the larger area (outer curve)